# Measure time in opencv c++ (has cuda) and cuda-C

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, cuda

I have written a function to add 2 images in CUDA-C and now I want to measure the time both CUDA-C and just use OpenCV C++ (library with CUDA). Is it right to use:

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;

cudaEventCreate(&start);
// ...
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
```

I want to measure both to find out which is faster?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is the wrong way to time CUDA events. To properly time a CUDA event, you do the following:

```cpp
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);

cudaEventRecord(start);
// .. Kernel
cudaEventRecord(stop);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
```

You can then use the *cudaEventElapsedTime()` function to measure the time elapsed in milliseconds as such:

```cpp
float time = 0;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
```

As for OpenCV using CUDA, I believe it is best to use CUDA's own timing mechanism (as shown above) to measure the performance of the function.